# Segmentation fault compiling CUDA "hello, world" with relocatable-device-code

Tags: cuda, gnu, nvcc

I'm trying my hand at using the `relocatable-device-code` flag. I have a large project that would be easier to maintain with small blocks of code.

I was able to get the project to compile. When trying to run it, I get a hard crash. When using the debugger:

```
(gdb) where
#0  0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
#1  0x00007fffffffe39c in ?? ()
#2  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

I've never seen a stack trace like that! I then reduced the amount of code until I came down to a singularity: `main.cu` file contains only

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
    std::cout << "hello, world" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Which still fails. I'm using the following flags to compile my `main.cu` file.

```
nvcc    -shared -rdc=true -arch=sm_20 -Xcompiler -fPIC -g -G
```

Do these make sense? Why the segmentation fault for such a simple progam?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `-shared` switch.  That option is not applicable when you are trying to generate an executable.

From the [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#options-for-altering-compiler-linker-behavior):

> Generate a shared library during linking. Note: when other linker options are required for controlling dll generation, use option -Xlinker.